# NSDate compare always returns NSOrderedSame

Tags: ios, compare, nsdate

I have a problem with NSDate comparison. I tried out several solutions that I found while googling my problem but nothing changes: I compare two dates and I always get NSOrderedSame or difference between NSTimeIntervals = 0.0000;

My code looks like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    for (checklisteModel *updateRecord in updateArray) 
    {

        NSDate *serverDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:updateRecord.last_update];

        NSString *lastUpdateFromLocalRecord = [self getLastUpdateForChecklisteItemWithID:updateRecord.checklisteID];
        NSDate *localDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:lastUpdateFromLocalRecord];

        NSDateFormatter* fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"checkliste ID: %i",updateRecord.checklisteID);
        NSLog(@"server Date: ----- %@",[fmt stringFromDate:serverDate]);
        NSLog(@"local Date: ----- %@",lastUpdateFromLocalRecord);



        NSLog(@"difference of dates: %f",[serverDate timeIntervalSinceDate:localDate]);


        NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [serverDate timeIntervalSinceDate:localDate];
        double secondsInMinute = 60;
        NSInteger secondsBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInMinute;

        if (secondsBetweenDates == 0)
            NSLog(@"seconds between == 0");
        else if (secondsBetweenDates < 0)
            NSLog(@"seconds between < 0");
        else
            NSLog(@"seconds between > 0");



        //last_update on server is earlier than local
        if ([serverDate compare:localDate] == NSOrderedAscending) 
        {

            NSLog(@"Server data is earlier than local data");
            NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"server data: %@, local data: %@",updateRecord.last_update,lastUpdateFromLocalRecord]);
        }
        // server data is later than local data
        else if ([serverDate compare:localDate] == NSOrderedDescending) 
        {

            NSLog(@"Server data is later than local data");
            NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"server data: %@, local data: %@",updateRecord.last_update,lastUpdateFromLocalRecord]);
        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"Server data and local data are the same");
        }
    }
```

And part of my debugging shows this:

```
checkliste ID: 21
server Date: ----- 
local Date: ----- 2012-10-29 10:13:46
difference of dates: 3810.000000
seconds between > 0
Server data is later than local data
server data: 2012-10-29 11:17:16, local data: 2012-10-29 10:13:46
```

Comment: Can you post how you init the `NSDateFormatter`? I believe the problem should be in there.

Comment: Most likely one or both of your NSDate objects is nil.  Note that you're not logging `serverDate`.

Comment: I have added the dateformatter for you. @Hot Licks: server date is in the NSLog, see how the date of the server is different to the local date in the debugging screen at the bottom.

Comment: No, `serverDate` IS NOT in the log.  `updateRecord.last_update` is in the log, and they are entirely different beasts.  Dump `serverDate` and I bet it will be nil.

Comment: ok, I changed it and serverDate really is nil.

Comment: the funny thing is that it now shows a difference in NSTimeInterval and that the server data is newer than the local data.

Comment: I don't understand this: `NSInteger secondsBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInMinute;` Time intervals are in seconds, so what you're getting should be named "minutesBetweenDates".

Comment: was just trying out some code of another person, i didn't want to get the exact time in seconds or minutes. I just wanted to compare which one of the dates is more recently so I can decide which record to save on both systems (server database and local database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"server Date: ----- %@",updateRecord.last_update);
```

You're not logging `serverDate` here, so as Hot Licks suggested, there's a good chance that it's nil. You can send messages to `nil` in Objective-C, and the result is `0` or `nil`. What do you think the value of NSOrderedSame is? I'll bet a dollar that it's `0`.

```
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
```

I notice that your date formatter's input format doesn't exactly match what you're logging, so maybe the difference between the expected input and what you're providing is enough to prevent the formatter from creating a date. Try adding seconds to the date format for `inputFormatter`.

Comment: ... Someone owes you a dollar

Comment: adding seconds to the formatter helped at least for the difference between the dates in seconds / minutes. this helps me alot since I just want to check if the date is below or over the local data time. So I will just compare if "secondsBetweenDates" is below, even or bigger than 0. :)